# spark action throwing 'Classpath contains multiple SLF4J bindings' error from oozie

Tags: scala, maven

I have a scala jar file which reads data from hive views and creates a csv file in hdfs , this jar is running fine in spark cluster mode when invoked from CLI , but when triggered from Oozie workflow it throws below error

```
 SLF4J : Classpath contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
 SLF4J : Found binding in [jar:file:/data/hadoop-data/9/yarn/nm/filecache/7505/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
 SLF4J : Found binding in [jar:file:/data/hadoop-data/1/yarn/nm/usercache/cntr/filecache/216569/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
 SLF4J : Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p2256.2455/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

 SLF4J : Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I have done some search and found out that adding exclusions in dependencies of pom.xml will do trick , so I have added below to my exclusions in pom.xml

```
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
```

but still I'm getting the same error when triggering the spark jar from oozie workflow

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: its because you have multiple `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar` in your classpath as you can see with your error. Its not an error I guess, its just information, isn't it?

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan , it's coming as stderr from oozie , and because of this the spark action is failing , as the jar is running successfully in cluster when ran from command line interface

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to check for bindings. I assume you're using eclipse for development, and this is a maven project.

- Go to you pom.xml
- In the dependencies tab, search for the binding, in your case slf4j.
- Right click on all and exclude them.

What it does basically is add exclusion blocks to you pom.xml like you mentioned up there, the advantage is you get to see if that dependency is coming from any other library.

Let me know if this helps. 
Cheers.

Comment: Hi @chitral verma I tried looking for slf4j in dependecies tab in pom.xml and don't find any to exclude

Comment: Instead of dependencies tab can you do the the same dependency hierarchy tab?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to multiple `jars` of `slf4j` used by different others `jars`. The easier solution is to add the latest or the higher version of `slf4j` in your dependency, which enforce to use only the latest `jar` which will be backward compatible.

You can also run `mvn dependency:tree` and search for the implementation of slf4j and exclude as

```
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After further research of log files I found out that the issue is due to hive-site.xml is not properly passed to spark action , spark action is expecting hive-site.xml from oozie workflow as my spark job contains reference to hive tables. After passing the hive-site.xml the issue got resolved

Thanks all for your time and suggestions.